# Is voltage sag safe if the voltage isn't too low?

Tags: lipo-batteries, batteries, battery-safety

I know that a liPo cell should never be below 3.0 volts, but can voltage sag during high throttle maneuvers damage the battery excessively even if the voltage it not below that level?

And if that is the case; should you try to limit how much the voltage sags by getting a battery with a higher C-rating, or will the difference be negligible if you go from, for example, 75 C to 100 C on a 1500 mAh battery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, voltage sag is perfectly normal and safe for the battery, so long as it remains above the recommended minimum voltage levels.

The C rating is important as the construction of a cell affects how quickly it can provide current. The internal surface area of the positive and negative terminals is related to the current it can provide - a larger surface area lowers the internal resistance and this causes less heating when discharging. This is why higher C packs are bulkier.